# CakePHP 2.0.x: ACL: Multiple Groups?

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.0

I know this question has been asked before, but I don't know if it's been asked specifically about CakePHP 2.0.x. I haven't been able to find any information about whether or not having users be a part of multiple groups is now possible with the ACL component. I never used the ACL component with CakePHP 1.3.x because it confused me. If it's better now, though, I'd like to use it so I don't re-invent the wheel by rolling my own. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It may be worth giving it a go and seeing what happens? I don't think ACL has been updated significantly that it can support User HABTM Group but I haven't dug deep enough into it yet.

Comment: What's the actual question? If it's possible to assign multiple groups to an ARO? I can only guess this from the question title, but there is no actual question stated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it or used it like this before, but I can imagine one way:

Have a `User` model and a `Group` model, and `User HATBM Group` as Shaz Amjad notes.

At the point you're doing your access control, fetch a list of all Groups that User belongs to (probably using bindModel)..

Then, something like:

```
$permits = array();
foreach ($thisUsersGroups as $group) {
   $permits[] = $this->Acl->check($group, 'myclass', 'update')
}
```

If `$permits` contains at least one `true`, they should be permitted.

There might well be a better or more automagic way of doing it, but I don't see what that shouldn't work in principle.